# No puedo cargar mis datos en datatabel php mysql

Tags: php, json, mvc, datatables, msql

Hola soy nuevo con datatables y php, quiero cargar mi datatable a partir de  mi controlador,el json por los visto, está bien generado, mi problema como paso esos datos a mi datatable.
Resltado que devuelve ProductoController:
{"sEcho":1,"iRecords":2,"iDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[["1","#01","Perno Directo","2432.00","1","--"],["2","#0","Perno Directo 2","2550.25","1","--"]]}

mi controlador:

```
public function listar_producto(){          
        $campos="*";            
        $consulta="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $campos FROM producto  ORDER BY nombre ASC LIMIT 1000";
        $conexion = MainModel::conectar();
        $datos = $conexion->query($consulta);
        $datos = $datos->fetchAll();
        $total = $conexion->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
        $total = (int) $total->fetchColumn();
        $list = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
            $list[]=array(
                "0"=>$datos[$i]["id"],
                "1"=>$datos[$i]["codigo"],
                "2"=>$datos[$i]["nombre"],
                "3"=>$datos[$i]["precio"],
                "4"=>$datos[$i]["categoria_id"],
                "5"=>$datos[$i]["estado"]
            );          
        }
        $resultado=array(
            "sEcho"=>1,
            "iRecords"=>$total,
            "iDisplayRecords"=>$total,
            "aaData"=>$list
        );
        
        return json_encode($resultado);
    
    }
```

mi js

```
var  json=<?php echo $ins_producto->listar_producto();?>; 
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#product_list').dataTable( {
          "aaData":json,          
        "language": {
           "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']
    });
    });
```

mi tabla
  `

```
   <table id="product_list" class="table table-bordered datatable" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Precio</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>Categoria</th>
              <th>Visible</th>
              <th>Opciones</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
      </tfoot>                     
    </table>
  <?php
          require_once "./controladores/AdministradorController.php";
          $ins_administrador = new AdministradorController();
        //  echo $ins_administrador->listar_usuario();
        ?>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ponlo así:

```
$('#product_list').dataTable({
  data: json.aaData,
});
```

De este modo le estas pasando una matriz a dataTables en su parámetro `data` pues es uno de los formatos que espera [segun su documentación](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Data-source-types).

En el siguiente snippet he recreado esta solución *(estate atento a los cambios que he hecho de columnas y sus nombres en el html)*:

```js
var json = {
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iRecords": 2,
  "iDisplayRecords": 2,
  "aaData": [
    ["1", "#01", "Perno Directo", "2432.00", "1", "--"],
    ["2", "#0", "Perno Directo 2", "2550.25", "1", "--"]
  ]
};

$('#product_list').dataTable({
  data: json.aaData
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<table id="product_list" class="table table-bordered datatable" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```